# How to make bottomNavigationBar at the top of the screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation, position, navigationbar, flutter-bottomnavigation

I Want to make a TopNavigationBar all tutorials that i seen is about bottomNavigationBar how i position it at the Top?

[I Want to make it like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt4Jf.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

that's absolutely not a `bottomNvigationBar` , this is a `TabBar` with `TabView` , you can google it but this is the official docs for tabs :

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

Comment: I use CustomScrollView with Slivers to hide the appBar when i scroll like facebook. But if i used TabBar i will not make this effect.